# TypeError: can't access property "call", modules[moduleId] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Sometimes, in my website I have a error in production; it's:

> TypeError: can't access property "call", modules[moduleId] is undefined

And I don't understand this error because it really only appears very rarely.

What is this error? If somebody can help me please explain it to me.

Because I looked for the error on the internet, but I have the impression that those who have it do not have the same concerns as me and that does not help me to understand the problem.

Comment: "those who have it do not have the same concerns as me" What are your concerns? We can't allay your concerns if we don't know what they are. Also, we'll need to see the code where this error occurs if you want us to explain it. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for more information on how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: It means that `modules` does not contain an element with the id held in `moduleId`. The id in `moduleId` is `"call"` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the object held in variable `modules` does not contain an property with the name held in `moduleId`.
The value of `moduleId` seems to be `"call"` in your example.

This means that `modules[moduleId] == undefined` for `moduleId == call`. Or also why `modules.call == undefined`.

You have to check where and why `"call"` is assigned to `moduleId` and/or why `modules` does not contain a property called `call`.